# Rails how get foreign_key on a mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

On a order confirmation both the seller and the user receive the confirmation but after add the seller_id or buyer_id rails spits out error!

i'm looking to suer where as a solution but did not find the specific ID

someone have a idea how to pass the foreign_key on a mailer?

thank's

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base


  belongs_to :seller, foreign_key: 'seller_id', class_name: 'Shop'
  belongs_to :buyer, foreign_key: 'buyer_id', class_name: 'User'

end





 def order_confirmation(order)

    @order = order
   @buyer = Order.where('buyer_id')
    mail(to: @buyer.email, subject: 'confirmation', &:html)
  end

 def order_confirmation_seller(order)
    @order = order
     @seller = Order.where('seller_id')
    mail(to: @seller.email, subject: 'confirmation', &:html)
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

`Order.where('buyer_id')` doesn't seem to be a valid thing. You can use `Order.where(buyer: order.buyer)` to fetch all the orders the buyer bought. But in the given case we have the order as a method argument.

I would recommend to use:

- `@buyer = order.buyer`
- `@seller = order.seller`

And a tip: `order_confirmation_for_seller` and `order_confirmation_for_buyer` could be a better naming.